# Composition of monotonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Given $f: \mathrm{R} \to \mathrm {R}$ , define $ f^2(x)= f(f(x)).$ Which of the following are true?

1. If $f$ is strictly monotonic, then $f^2$ is strictly increasing.
2. If $f^2(x) = -x $ for all $x \in \mathrm{R},$ then $ f $ is one- one.
3. There does not exist a continuous function $f: \mathrm{R} \to \mathrm {R}$ such that $f^2(x)= -x$ for all $x \in \mathrm{R}.$

I think $1$ is true since function composition will always give increasing function for strictly monotone functions (either increasing like $x$, $\log x$ or decreasing like $e^{-x}$ or $1/x$) but unable to find function for option $2$ and $3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I leave the first to you, the intuition is correct but you should formalize the math.

---

We answer the second and third. In points :

- Let $f^2(x) = -x$ for some continuous function $f$.
- Prove that $f$ is one-one as follows : start with $f(x) = f(y)$. Apply $f$ to both sides. Simplify using our assumption and conclude $x=y$, so $f$ is one-one.
- Show that any one-one continuous function on $\mathbb R$ is strictly monotonic (use the Intermediate Values Theorem). Hence $f$ is strictly monotonic.
- Conclude from part $1$ that $f^2$ is strictly increasing . But $-x$ is not, so that gives a contradiction.

Comment: For the first part, if $f$ is strictly increasing then $x <y \implies f(x) <f(y)$ which further implies $ f(f(x)) < f(f(y))$ and if $f$ is strictly decreasing then $x <y \implies f(x) >f(y)$, now $f(x)> f(y)$ further implies $ f(f(x)) < f(f(y))$ , so in both cases $f^2$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Yes, that is right!